# Java Android studio: change an attribute of a View inside its own listener

Tags: java, android, view, onclicklistener

I have a question about the Android Studio:

I have an Image view. Let's call it ImageView. I call the method `setOnCLickListener` on this ImageView with a listener new `View.OnclickListener()`. 
In the method `onClick()` of this listener, I change an attribute (the color, the image itself...) of this imageView. For example, I change the image with `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_image)`. I then wait for 10 sec with `Thread.sleep(10000)`. I then set back the previous image with `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.previous_image)`.

Here is my question:

I expect the ImageView to change its image for 10 sec and then have the previous image back. However, I see no change on this ImageView. I only see the first image...Could someone explain me why?

I hope I was clear enough...Thank you in advance for your help :) !!

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should read the [Processes and Threads](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads) guide to understand how threading works on Android.

If you're done with with that, you'll understand that what you do is really bad because you freeze the main (UI) thread which means the application will not respond to any events until the 10 seconds pass. This also results in an [ANR](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html) (Application Not Responding) dialog which is *pretty bad* UX.

You basically need to delegate the waiting period to another thread (or a queue at least), then when the time comes, go back to the UI thread and set whatever view attribute you want. There are many ways to achieve this, you should read [Communicating with the UI Thread](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html) for more details. Here's just a quick sample:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // write here what you want to happen in 10 seconds on the UI thread
    }
}, 10000); // 10s = 10,000ms
```

Here are some notes though:

1. Save the `Runnable` you create here to a variable because if the user navigates away from this screen within the 10 seconds, it will still run the code inside, which might result in various exceptions. In this case you need to remove that `Runnable` from the handler by calling `handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);` when the user leaves the screen.
2. Don't create a new `Handler` instance every time the click event happens. Create it in the `Activity`'s `onCreate(...)` method and use that instance in the rest of the screen.
3. You *could* create the `Handler` without the `Looper` parameter, which would create the handler for the current thread's `Looper` and that would be fine now since it's being created on the UI thread. However, I decided it's better to show you the safer way since you might end up doing something similar on a background thread that could result in unexpected behavior if you don't understand the threading yet.

Comment: Great it is working now...But i ll continue studying the subject!! THx a lot for your clear answer!

Answer (score 3):

`R.id.drawable.previous_image` ?. It should be `R.drawable.previous_image`

Comment: Yes sorry I meant R.drawable.previous_image! THx for catching it! I have just edited it!